# SML using reduce and map to traverse an n-ary tree

Tags: tree, sml

I'm new to SML.

Say I have the following datatype:

```
datatype 'a tree = leaf of 'a | node of 'a tree list
```

and the function `val leaves = fn : 'a tree -> 'a list`:

```
fun leaves (leaf x) = [x]
  | leaves (node []) = []
  | leaves (node [x]) = leaves x
  | leaves (node (x::xs)) = (leaves x) @ (leaves (node xs))
```

If I have

```
val t = node [node [leaf 1,
              node [leaf 2, leaf 3],
              leaf 4]];
```

Then, `leaves t` will return `[1, 2, 3, 4]` for me.

What I want to ask is that, does this is possible to be rewritten by using `reduce` and `map`?

Given reduce:

```
fun reduce g [x] = x
  | reduce g (x::xs) = (g x (reduce g xs))
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a recurring pattern of starting with too many clauses.

Start with the two necessary ones:

```
fun leaves (leaf x) = [x]
  | leaves (node xs) = ???
```

Now, `xs` is a list.
`map` transforms a list into a different list.
`reduce` reduces a list to a single value.

This suggests that you want something of the form

```
| leaves (node xs) = reduce f (map g xs)
```

Determining `f` and `g` left as an exercise.

Comment: After doing some research on `List.concat`, I know what `f` and `g` be like!

Answer (score 0):

In ML there is a convention, not enforced by syntax in SML, to have data constructors begin with uppercase and values (including functions) begin with lowercase. In pattern matching this makes them more easily distinguishable, since syntactically, `node` could be either a data constructor or a variable, it's not possible to tell without inspecting the whole code.

StackOverflow tends to agree with us, since its syntax highlighter isn't very context-aware and can't paint the data constructors a special color unless we follow this convention.

So:

```
datatype 'a tree = Leaf of 'a | Node of 'a tree list
```

---

molbdnilo already showed how you can simplify the patterns in `leaves` down two:

```
fun leaves (Leaf x) = [x]
  | leaves (Node ts) = ???
```

(Note that I changed the casing of the constructors and renamed `xs` into `ts` because it's a list of trees.)

To complete this function using recursion, I would say that you could go in two ways here. As you will see, there are trade-offs in both directions, which I'll mention:

- Stick with two patterns and handle recursion on `xs` in a separate, mutually recursive function:

  ```
  fun leaves (Leaf x) = [x]
    | leaves (Node ts) = nodes ts

  and nodes [] = []
    | nodes (t::ts) = leaves n @ nodes ts
  ```

  Having two functions that may call one another is just a bit mind-bending. You have to keep reminding yourself that `t` is a tree, so `leaves` should be called on that, but `ts` is a list of trees, so `nodes` should be called on that. But besides using `and` instead of `fun` on subsequent, mutually recursive functions, the syntax is not that bad.
- Go to three patterns and handle recursion of both the tree and its inner lists by matching two levels deep:

  ```
  fun leaves (Leaf x) = [x]
    | leaves (Node []) = []
    | leaves (Node (t::ts)) = leaves t @ leaves (Node ts)
  ```

  Having just one function seems simpler, but the downside is that pattern matching gets a bit more tricky: You don't just match that the input is a `Node`, but specifically that it's a `Node` with either no children (`Node []`) or a node with at least one child (`Node (t::ts)`). The complexity here is that while you pattern matched successfully to deconstruct a single `t` that can be passed recursively to `leaves` (`leaves t`), handling the rest of `ts` (an `'a tree list`), you don't have a function that handles such a list. But you almost do: If you put back the `Node` on `ts` (`Node ts`), you get an `'a tree` with that list of child nodes. And you *do* have a function for handling one tree.

You can decide for yourself over time which idea is harder to work with.

Maybe it turns out you like both for different occasions.

---

> What I want to ask is that, does this is possible to be rewritten by using `reduce` and `map`?

Yes.

Comment: Thanks for ur comment! I didn't notice the naming convention before. Yup, I do agree with you that we should stick with it :)